# PCRE install? Plus a couple of other questions

Tags: php

I'm pretty new to PHP so sorry about the possible misuse of terminology here. I went to use the "ereg()" function to search a string for a substring with regular expressions but then saw on the PHP manual that is was deprecated in favour of "PCRE". So I went to use "preg_match()" but got the following errors (note that ereg() probably wasn't working when I had it there before):

> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: page in C:\wamp\www\snip\snip\snip\snip\snip\index.php on line 8

and

> ( ! ) Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\snip\snip\snip\snip\snip\index.php on line 8

and

> ( ! ) Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:\wamp\www\snip\snip\snip\snip\snip\index.php on line 8

from the following code:

```
<?php

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/class_lib.php");

$page = new Page();

function which_tab() {
    preg_match("snip:.................", $page->content, $result);
    explode(" ", $result, "<");
    return $result[1];
}

$tab_which = which_tab();

$get_tab = file_get_contents($tab_which."txt");

$page->meta = array
(
'title' => 'snip',
'description' => 'snip'
);

$page->content = "
stuff: stuff<br />
snip: 'stuff'<br />
stuff: 'stuff'<br />
stuff: stuff<br />
stuff: stuff<br /><br />
<a href=\"../../stuff/\">stuff</a><br /><br />
stuff<br /><br />
<div id=\"tab\">
<pre>
".$get_tab."
</pre>
</div>
<br/><a href=\"stuff\">stuff</a> stuff
";

$page->Display();

?>
```

I understand that this probably isn't the most pragmatic way of doing things but this script is for personal use and I want to build familiar with these features of PHP.

I basically want the file to be included to depend on what text is present to the right of "snip" which is unique in the page. This particular word (which will change depending on the document) will be followed by a line break so I've used '<' as the delimiter on explode().

Are the above errors being generated because I need to install PCRE?

I also get these errors... (alot, I know):

> ( ! ) Warning: explode() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given in C:\wamp\www\snip\snip\snip\snip\snip\index.php on line 9

and

> ( ! ) Warning: file_get_contents(txt) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\snip\snip\snip\snip\snip\index.php on line 15

But this error should be resolved if I can get the preg_match working I guess.

I know there's alot going wrong here so I'd appreciate any help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need it to install - you already have it.

But you need to rewrite a little your regular expressions, since `preg_match` uses another engine (thus syntax)

```
preg_match("snip:.................", $page->content, $result);
```

would become

```
preg_match('~snip:.................~', $page->content, $result);
```

Where `~` sign is a regex delimiter mentioned in errors.

Other errors are self-descriptive enough:

`Notice: Undefined variable: page` --- means (surpise-surprise) that you're trying to read the not defined variable value

`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object` --- means that you're trying to access the property of an object, but actually variable doesn't contain any (it contains some scalar value or `null` instead)

Comment: Sorry, could you tell me how "define the variable" - it's probably real simple but I'm new to this. It doesn't matter that the function using the content variable is called before the content variable is defined does it?

Comment: @Dan: `$variable = 'value';` -- here is a definition. And it **does matter**.` `$page` variable is not in the scope of function, so you cannot see it inside: http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.phpAn error occurred during comment submission(click on this box to dismiss) Pass it using function parameters

Comment: Okay, that solved it - thanks :) Now I just have this error (well two more but they'll be solved once this one is solved): `( ! ) Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\wamp\www\snip\snip\snip\snip\snip\index.php on line 11` Any ideas?

Comment: When I change the $result in explode() to $result[0], I get: `( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp\www\projects\tabs\colour_haze\tempel\aquamaria\index.php on line 11` - I assuming this means that the preg_match didn't find a result but it should have done - does this mean that there's something wrong with the preg_match?

Comment: @Dan: discover `var_dump($varname);` function for youself and see what **actually** is in the variable

Comment: Ah, I'm gonna leave it. I think I should have been using preg_grep(). I just don't see why I need to define the "content" variable if it's already defined in the document (main body of text). I thought maybe it was because the function ran before the content was loaded but even when I put the function after the content, it gave `Undefined variable: content in`...